# Request for AddAngleBetweenVectorsCost

Tags: drake, inverse-kinematics

For IK, I find the `AngleBetweenVectorsConstraint` to be very useful, but I have come across a problem which requires a cost rather than a constraint. I was wondering if an `AddAngleBetweenVectorsCost` could possibly be implemented?

Comment: I will implement this later today.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/17821